# Bootstrap - blue links

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have just created new ASP.NET MVC 5 application which uses by default Bootstrap 3.0. Please tell me why all glyphs icons which I use and action links are blue. You can see this in attached image. I didn't change anything in bootstap.css or any other .css file. Shouldn't it be black by default? How to repair this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The glyphicons are probably inside of some link tags styled with a blue color and since the glyphicons are simply normal text (just a different font), they inherit the color of their parent element.

If you want them to be black everywhere you could add some css like:

```
.glyphicon {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Altought this would probably work i would advice against using the !important keyword as it will often make the css more obscure.